# Datagridviewcomboboxcolumn default selection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

There are two status in my database, they are "Arrived", "Pending". I want when my form loads I need my DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to Initialize each cells with those status. This is the code I tried:

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cb.HeaderText = "Status";
        cb.Name = "Status";
        cb.Width = 100;
        cb.Items.AddRange("Arrived", "Pending");
        dgPurchase.Columns.Add(cb);
        string stat= "";

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgPurchase.Rows)
        {
            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Purchase_Status FROM PurchasedProducts WHERE Purchase_Order_No = " + row.Cells["Purchase Order No"].Value + "AND Purchase_Product_ID = " + row.Cells["Product ID"].Value, connection);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    stat= reader["Purchase_Status"].ToString();
                }
                row.Cells["Status"].Value = stat;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Report", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

When I execute this code, I don't get the default value on DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.[image]

Please help me!

Comment: @Grant Winney I already checked with MessageBox, "stat" has the value

Comment: I guess the problem is with `row.Cells["Status"].Value = stat;` Is there any other way to select a default value, like SelectedIndex in ComboBox?

Comment: I meant the value in the db should be showing in each cells while form loading